# Inserting into mySQL inserts duplicates? - on duplicate doubles entry

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates

I am inserting search terms into a database, and when I run it to test, I am seeing duplicates inserted into the database? Any idea why that would be? here is a sample of my insert function  -

*Update - I am inserting, and it no longer inserts as a duplicate, but I am trying to get the on duplicate to work - and the on duplicate updates the popularity by 2 each time? what do I have wrong here?

```
$entryDate = date("c");
$insertsearchquery="insert into article_searches (termSafe,entryDate) values (\"$termSafe\",\"$entryDate\") on duplicate key update popularity=popularity+1";

mysql_query($insertsearchquery);
```

Comment: Hows your table defined? Any (unique or primary) keys?

Comment: My id field is a Primary with a type BTREE set to Unique.

Comment: Unless you are inserting an id, this has no *meaning* for the validity of the columns `termSafe` or `entryDate` - *What* do you expect when inserting an existing *termSafe*-Value? *what* do you expect, when inserting an existing *entryDate* value?

Comment: _termSafe_ will be the searched term and then _entryDate_ will be the date and time it was searched.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates, you need a `unique` index or constraint (these are really the same thing) or a primary key.  Assuming that you mean duplicates are caused by both values, you can prevent insertion by creating a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_table2_termSafe_entryDate on table2(termSafe, entryDate);
```

I would comment that it seems strange that the table name is a parameter in your code.  Normally, having multiple tables with the same structure is a sign of poor database design.  In most cases, it is better to have one large table rather than many small tables.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you asked another question, but since you're writing a searching system consider to add a column that count the times you inserted that key:

```
popularity (smallint unsigned not null default 1)
```

and adding

```
on duplicate key update popularity=popularity+1
```

at the end of your insert query (this require a primary key on columns termSafe and entryDate)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a primary key set on the table into which you're inserting there will be no logic preventing insertion of duplicate data.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html